# how to make app ask permision automnatical when install

Tags: android, android-studio, android-permissions

i want to make my app to ask for permission when install , permission for storage write and read , what should i do what code i have to add and where to add

i have tried adding permision in androidmanifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permissio
```

what else i have to do?

Comment: For devices using Android 23 or above you should ask the STORAGE PERMISSION at runtime.

Comment: how should i do that, i build the app for 8.1 android ,can u guide me through it , am new to this

Answer (score 0):

If You set Your targetApi to 22 in gradle, it will ask permissions on install, but then You will not be able to upload Your app to Google Play.

```
targetSdkVersion 22
```